# How to Convert Object to Array of Object? in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a problem in my code, the problem is I want to convert an object to an array, but according to the example below for the object can be seen in the image link.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/67XMp.png (the object output)

example:

```js
{
  [
    0:{"name": "fiqih", "diskusi": 5}
    1:{"name": "Nah", "diskusi": 2}
    2:{"name": "Nah2", "diskusi": 4}
    etc..
  ]
}
```

Comment: Could you please be more clear with your question? Provide both your object and the desired array of object. The image and the object you have put in your question seem to have very little relation to one another.

Comment: After edit it's better but read this for asking better : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Just place your object in an array or use `new Array()` like below

```js
const obj = {foo: 'bar'};
const arr = [obj]; // or new Array(obj);

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
var obj= {"1": 1, "2": 2}

var arr = Object.entries(obj)
```